# Are there ternary operators that aren't some form of a conditional operator

Tags: language-agnostic, ternary-operator, conditional-operator

I recently asked a meta question about the validity of replacing the term "ternary" operator with "conditional" operator.  One of the comments on my meta question stated the following:

> a ternary operator is any operator that takes 3 arguments. The conditional operator is a ternary operator but it's not the only one (although in particular programming languages it might be the only one).

This seems to indicate that a strict reading of the term ternary operator means an operator that takes three arguments.  However in my own experience, and after glancing through the wikipedia page on the ternary operator I didn't see an example of a ternary operator that wasn't a conditional ternary operator of one form or another.

In practice is there a **built-in to the language** example of a ternary operator that isn't of the following form (a conditional operator)?

```
if arg1 then arg2 else arg3
```

I'm not looking for a specific language, although one with at least moderate popularity would be preferred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am quite sure that there is no other ternary operator in any of the mainstream programming languages. However, in lisp-like languages there is not really a difference between a function and an operator, therefore any function with three arguments is like a ternary operator.

The interesting point of your question is: Why is that so? I believe there is one main reason:

Why are there operators at all? Can't you always use a function? Sure, but operators can make code easier to read. But in general, that's only true for unary and binary operators, where you put one argument to the right and optionally the other argument to the left of the operator. With ternary operators, there is no obvious place for the third argument. The conditional assignment operator also suffers from this issue, but it is so useful that it got established anyway.